# Current user directive in profile doesn't work with tabs on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stackexchange.com, network-profile

If you go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity it will open the *all actions* tab for the currently logged in user.

When going to https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity, it does open the current user, but not the *activity* tab (names are different, but the URL parameters are the same). Instead, it remains at the first tab, *top*.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed now; thanks - well spotted

Comment: I see. That was a quick fix. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I can roll it back and schedule it for 6-8 weeks if that helps... ;p

Comment: Meh. This is good. :)